# vim delete/unset environment variable

Tags: vim

In vim, I can set env vars via 
`:let $MyVar = 1`

`echom $MyVar` will print `1` after setting `$MyVar` via the code above.

Is there a way to delete that variable from the environment?

Comment: Why do you want to set an environment variable in Vim? Why not a variable?

Comment: @romainl, there are plenty use cases like starting a script that reads environment variables, or even simply to guide `:make` into using a compiler or another through `$CC`, `$CXX` and so on. I must admit that I don't need to unset environment variables that often, but it occurred a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible yet. I've opened an issue on the subject: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1116

In the mean time instead of unsetting environment variables, I set them in very narrow scopes: when I call `system()` or when I call `job_start()`.

In order to simplify my workflow, I emulate some kind of [project environment variables](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Project.md). In short, that's environment variables that exists only in some buffers, and then when I call [`lh#os#system()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/os.vim#L89), I inject those variables on the fly.

NB: you don't need to use `p:$VARIABLES`, `lh#os#system()` can also receive environment variables through its second and optional parameter, e.g.:

```
let r = lh#os#system('make foo', {'CXXFLAGS': 'std=c++14, 'CXX': 'clang++'})
```

Behind the scenes, I create a temporary file that I fill with as many `export var=expr` lines as needed before I execute the requested command.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is now supported via `:unlet` as of [vim 8.0.1832](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1116#issuecomment-393514806)

For example, to remove a variable `$FOO`:

```
:unlet $FOO
```